# Python: Remove Almost-Duplicates from a List of objects

Tags: python, list, duplicates, tuples

How can I remove all tuples in the following list of tuples **where only one specific index is never a duplicate**? In this case, I need to remove duplicates of each tuple's second value (aka index 1).

```
[(1051,97),(1051,132),(1048,132),(1048,283),(1048,438)]
                 ^^^        ^^^
```

The desired output:

```
[(1051,97),(1051,132),(1048,283),(1048,438)]
```

Bonus points for being able to retain the first-order precedence shown in the above desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a set of all index 1 elements you encounter as you iterate and only include tuples in the final result if its index 1 element hasn't been encountered:

```
lst = [(1051,97),(1051,132),(1048,132),(1048,283),(1048,438)]

s = set()
res = []
for i, j in lst:
    if j not in s:
        s.add(j)
        res.append((i,j))

print(res)
# [(1051, 97), (1051, 132), (1048, 283), (1048, 438)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [(1051,97),(1051,132),(1048,132),(1048,283),(1048,438)]
lst = list(reversed([(v, k) for k, v in {t[1]: t[0] for t in reversed(lst)}.items()]))
print(lst)
# [(1051, 97), (1051, 132), (1048, 283), (1048, 438)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df.loc[df[1].drop_duplicates().index].values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a reversed dictionary. Since dictionary keys are always unique, the dupicates will be naturally eliminated:

```
l = [(1051,97),(1051,132),(1048,132),(1048,283),(1048,438)]
[(x,y) for y,x in {y:x for x,y in l}.items()]
#[(1051, 97), (1048, 132), (1048, 283), (1048, 438)]
```

This solution does not preserve the order.